# Can some one help debug this C++ code? Don't really understand what the error messages points to

Tags: c++

```
bool if_duplicate (const vector <Assignment> & assgt, const string & ID) {
   int i;
   
   for (i=0; i<assgt.size();i++) {
      if (assgt[i].getId() == ID) {
         return true;
      } 
      else {
   return false;
      }
   }
}
```

error message i keept getting: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
285 | }

Comment: If `assgt.size()` was `0` for example, you would reach the end of your function without returning anything.

Comment: Step through the function in your debugger and you will immediately see the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that code does what you expect it to in any event; why have a loop if you intend to inspect only the first element (if one exists)?

Comment: Even if the diagnostic gets resolved by adding a final `return` I fear that's only going to hide the forest behind the tree. The returned value will be determined by the first value in the non-empty vector. The `for` loop is not doing anything useful. It is almost certain that the entire algorithm is broken. The compiler diagnostic is just a symptom.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning not an error.
The warning says that you are have no `return` from your function in the case the for loop won't run.

Try this:

```cpp
bool if_duplicate (const vector <Assignment> & assgt, const string & ID) {
   int i;
   
   for (i = 0; i < assgt.size(); i++) {
      if (assgt[i].getId() == ID) {
         return true;
      } 
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

I also think that your function doesn't really do what you want. Did you mean to write this?

```cpp
bool if_duplicate (const vector <Assignment> & assgt, const string & ID) {
   int i;
   
   for (i = 0; i < assgt.size(); i++) {
      if (assgt[i].getId() == ID) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: First thank you very much for your help! The problem I'm solving is to check if the new input ID, a string, already exist in previous inputs. So I'm trying to use a for loop to call the ID of each object stored in the vector and compare each one with the new input

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong (buggy). The complete function you can write with this one line. Test, you'll have same result:

```
bool if_duplicate (const vector <Assignment> & assgt, const string & ID) {

   return (assgt.size() != 0) && (assgt[0].getId() == ID);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing as the original code, nor does it do what the original code was intended to do.

Comment: @Sneftel, i know what original code intended to do :) that's why have written 1 line to show that it does. It does the same, except exit on "size() == 0". If size() != 0, the original code exits on the first loop, i.e. index == 0